# Liferay notifications-portlet

Tags: xml, notifications, liferay

How to add approve and disapprove buttons in notifications portlet Liferay in Unread tab. I've added the buttons in /tomcat/webapps/notifications-portlet/notifications/VIEW_ENTRIES.JSP but the buttons also appears in All Notifications tab even if I already read (approved or disapproved) it.

Thanks[image: notifications]

Comment: Some more information would help: Which Liferay version? How did you add the buttons? And which Liferay version are you using (6.2 has not view_entries.jsp)? And why did you tag with XML?

Comment: My liferay version is 6.2 EE. I wanted to create approve & reject buttons in UNREAD tab of the notification portlet. I edited the view_entries.jsp inside this path (tomcat/webapps/notifications-portlet/notifications). But when I click the ALL NOTIFICATION tab.. it also has buttons. 

How will I achieve this? Thanks pls help. any hint will do.

Comment: With "how" I meant a code snippet. I would guess you need to create a condition around your buttons...